# Calculating the pressure inside catenoid formed using soap film?

Tags: pressure, fluid-statics, surface-tension, bubbles

Soap film will not readily form a cylinder, instead, it will form a catenoid if it's circular faces are flat. I know that this happens to minimise surface area.

But how to prove that this provides the minimum surface area?

Is there an expression to calculate the radius of curvature of the curved surface, and to calculate the pressure inside the catenoid bubble?

Answer (score 1):

The youtube channel 'Standup Maths' has a video about the [soap film between two rings](https://youtu.be/31Om4VrSzb8) problem.

As you mention: the cross section of that surface is a catenary.

About the strategy to find the shape of that surface.

For simplicity I will use the simplest mathematical expresssion for the catenary curve:

$$ f(x) = \cosh(x)  \tag{1} $$

At $x=0$ the curve is horizontal, and for simplicity I place the ring at $x=1$.

We divide the length from $x=0$ to $x=1$ in small subsections. For each subsection along the x-axis there is a corresponding narrow ring of soap film.

We set up an expression for the area of such a narrow ring. The total surface area is obtained by integrating the areas of all of those rings from $x=0$ to $x=1$.

Interestingly, it's actually not necessary to go all the way to setting up that integral.

The expression for the area of each ring is:

$$ 2 \pi y \sqrt{1 + (\tfrac{dy}{dx})^2} \tag{2} $$

As you go from $x=0$ to $x=1$ the curve is getting steeper all the way. The ring forces a particular diameter so that is a given. Close to the ring it pays for the curve to be at its steepest; you want to get to a smaller diameter quickly. Close to $x=0$ the circumference is smaller, so you want the curve to be less steep there.

The area of each narrow ring is given by the *product* of two factors: the circumference of the narrow ring, and the width of the narrow ring.

The circumference is determined by the radial distance, the width follows from the local slope of the curve.

At every value for the y-coordinate (of the curve) you can compare the contribution of the circumference to the contribution from the width.

The minimal surface has the following property:
At every point from $x=0$ to $x=1$ the contribution from the circumference and the contribution from the width *change at the same rate*.

The way to assess rate of change of each specific contributions is to use [partial differentiation](https://www.khanacademy.org/math/multivariable-calculus/multivariable-derivatives/partial-derivative-and-gradient-articles/a/introduction-to-partial-derivatives)

About that *change at the same rate*:
Consider what happens when you make the curve too steep. That reduces the contribution of circumference, but there is a penalty: the steeper the curve the larger the contribution from the width of the narrow ring.

The sweet spot is where along the entire domain the rate of change of the two contributions match each other.

Another way to see it in terms of matching rate of change: the catenoid is a minimal surface. That means the *sum* of the partial derivatives of the contributions to the surface area is zero. (When a function is at a minimum the derivative is zero.) Therefore the minimal surface has the property that the rate of change of the two contributions match each other.

In all:
the problem can be solved with differential calculus, using partial differentiation. The sweet spot is when the two partial derivatives are equal in magnitude everywhere.